# Is there a way to avoid columns from GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My table has columns such as ID,Perdium and Location so I want to calculate all the perdiums given to an employee and the perdium share given in NY. The issue which I am facing is that SQL Server engine is throwing as error stating that location column isnt present in the GROUP BY clause(as needed in my use-case).If I include the location in the Group By clause I always get NYPerdiumShare as 1 which is not what I am expecting. Is there any workaround to this?

```
WITH CTE_Employee AS
    (
        SELECT  ID,
                SUM(Perdium) AS TotalPerdium,
                CASE WHEN Location='NY' THEN SUM(Perdium) ELSE NULL END AS NYPerdium FROM EmployeePerdium
        GROUP BY ID
    )

SELECT  ID,
        TotalPerdium,
        NYPerdium/TotalPerdium AS NYPerdiumShare 
    FROM CTE_Employee
```

Comment: [Perdium](http://www.ibsgroup.org/forums/topic/91277-perdium/) and IBS? [Per diem](https://www.osc.state.ny.us/agencies/travel/reimbrate.htm)? I'd want to know which I'm being given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can eliminate the need to group by on anything other than `ID` by rewriting your query as follows to hide `CASE` inside an aggregate function:

```
WITH CTE_Employee AS (
    SELECT
        ID
    ,   SUM(Perdium) AS TotalPerdium
    ,   SUM(CASE WHEN Location='NY' THEN Perdium ELSE 0 END) AS NYPerdium
    FROM EmployeePerdium
    GROUP BY ID
)
SELECT
    ID
,   TotalPerdium
,   NYPerdium/TotalPerdium AS NYPerdiumShare 
FROM CTE_Employee
```

Comment: an integer division would be performed here.

Comment: @vkp I'm assuming that `Perdium` is not an integer, because it usually means an amount of money.

Comment: sure..a valid assumption.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a cte here. Just use the `sum` window function.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
ID,
SUM(Perdium) OVER() as TotalPerdium
SUM(CASE WHEN Location='NY' THEN 1.0*Perdium ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY ID)
/SUM(Perdium) OVER() AS NYPerdium 
FROM EmployeePerdium
```